# How to extract part of a line in a text file and print it to an output file in Perl (Code half-written)

Tags: perl

I have a large .txt file, a part of which is shown below -

```
ID   SNP
FT   SNP             102
FT                   /note="refAllele: C SNPstrains: 4395_8_10=A 4395_8_7=A 4395_8_9=A     "
FT                   /colour=1
FT   SNP             1299
FT                   /note="refAllele: A SNPstrains: 6437_8_6=T (non-synonymous) (AA Gin->His) "
FT                   /colour=2
FT   SNP             2134
FT                   /note="refAllele: C SNPstrains: 4395_8_12=T "
FT                   /colour=1
FT   SNP             3205
FT                   /note="refAllele: C SNPstrains: 6437_8_12=T (synonymous) "
```

I have this script as well (which I did not write) -

```
$cod{1} = "Int";
$cod{2} = "non";
$cod{3} = "syn";
$cod{4} = "stop";

$file = "Whole.pl";
open IN, "$file";
open OUT, ">whole2";
print OUT "Coordinate   Type    Strains\n";

while (<IN>) {

    if (m/^FT\s+SNP\s+(\d+)/) {

        $SNP = $1;      
    }
    elsif (m/^FT\s+\/note="(.*)"/) {

        $line = $1;
        $count = ($line =~ tr/=/=/);
    }
    elsif (m/^FT\s+\/colour=(\d+)/) {

        if ($cod{$1}) {

            print OUT "$SNP $cod{$1} $count\n";
        }
        elsif (!$cod{$1}) {

            print OUT "$SNP colour $1 $count\n";
        }
    }
}
```

It creates a new file. For the above data it would create this -

```
Coordinate  Type    Strains 
102          Int    3
1299         non    1
2134         Int    1
3205         syn    1
```

I am very new to perl and programming in general, and think I just about understand what this script is doing. However, for strains that show a non-synonymous mutation (such as the second one in the .txt file), I would like to have a fourth column in the output file which details the amino acid change (e.g. (AA Gin->His), end of the sixth line in the .txt file). Also, I would ideally like to just have non-synonymous mutations shown in the output, and leave the "syn" and "int" out altogether.

I have tried numerous ways to do this but none have worked. Please can you show me a way to do this?

Many thanks in advance.

Max

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assumptions:

1. Your `/note` may contain an amino acid change as last element. It must be enclosed with parens and start with the letters `AA`, followed by a sequence of one or more letters, followed by `->`, followed by another sequence of one or more letters.
2. You are only interested in the `non` type.

In your first `elsif`, we have to match the `$line` against a possible amino change:

```
}elsif(m/^FT\s+\/note="(.*)"/){
        $line=$1;
        $line =~ m/\((AA \w+->\w+)\)\s*$/;
        $change = $1 || "";
        ...;
```

In your second elsif, we print only if `$cod{$1}` is equal to `non`:

```
}elsif(m/^FT\s+\/colour=(\d+)/){
   print OUT "$SNP $count $change\n" if $cod{$1} eq "non";
   # inner if/else not needed any longer.
}
```

Also, your table headers at the top have to change:

```
print OUT "Coordinate   Strains Change\n";
```

You will have to re-align the columns manually.

This would print something like

```
Coordinate      Strains Change
1299    1       AA Gin->His
```

on the example input.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, I have applied the code and it works very well, many thanks!

Comment: @user1751679 You should accept the answer if it solved your problem. (there is a place to click on the left of it by the up/down arrows).

Comment: I have been using this code (which worked before) for another text file, formatted in exactly the same way (from what I have seen), but now I am given an error:

Use of uninitialised values ($count or $change) in concatenation (.) or string at line 23. The line in question is "print OUT "$SNP $count $change\n" if $cod{$1} eq "non";"

What could this be?

Comment: Put the following code before the `while` loop: `$count="<<UNDEFINED>>"; $change="<<UNDEFINED>>";`. Are these markers visible in the output, or do you still get the warning? The warning should also be telling you at what line of the input you are currently. How does the input look like there? The `$change` variable *cannot* be undefined unless a `/colour` line precedes the first `/note` line. The `$count` variable cannot be undefined unless a `/colour` line precedes the first `SNP` line. Can you verify that the input holds to this schema?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.

I put the markers in, and the output came as before except the Strains and Change columns were <<UNDEFINED>> for all values as expected. The lines the warning referred to previously were the "/colour" lines of non-synonymous changes, so line 7 in the example text I gave at the top of the page. The input does hold to SNP line first, followed by /note, and then by /colour, as in the example text.

Comment: This is confusing :) Maybe open a new question so that other people can help?